# Check remote file existance with Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, http, flex3, stream

In Flex 3/AS 3, what would be a good way to check if a remote file exists?
I'm thinking in PHP ways where you'd try to "fopen" a remote path (like "http://example.com/somefile.exe"), and see if it works or not. I'm not asking to just download all of the file, I just want to know if the file is there (and accessible).

Comment: where is the file and what is it (i.e. a windows exe at the end of an http link in your example above - which is very strange by the way)?  Depending on the answer to that you would have a few options.

Comment: In my case, yes http but no, not an exe. It will be a movie file, probably .mp4, .flv, or similar.

Comment: I have to say, looking at this old question, this is not something I would ask today. File existance over the web, when talking http, should of course be handled by the http protocol. Ie, if you get an 404, the page doesn't exist. And handle what fits you best if you get other respones, like server error, access denied etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need to attempt to load the file. If you get an IOError, the file doesn't exist (or your path is wrong). If it starts loading, by triggering a progress event then it exists. You can then cancel the remainder of the loading.

Alternatively you could try calling a PHP script from Flash which does what you have described, this could return a simple true/false.

Comment: The thing is, if the file does not exist, the web server returns a 404 page or similar (actually in my case, the front page is returned... blasted URL rewrites etc), and technically that page will be successfully downloaded.
I'm going for a solution that is close to your alternate - I'm checking on the server side (using PHP in this case) if the file exists or not - and just adds a "no file found" parameter to the flashvars. Which means the checking doesn't really take place in the flash client application. I guess this is good enough for me now.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best code I found for the job

```
var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
urlStream.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, streamHandler);
urlStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, streamHandler);
urlStream.load(new URLRequest("SOME_FILE"));

function streamHandler(e:Event):void {
    urlStream.close();
    if(e.type == Event.OPEN){
        trace("FILE EXISTS");
    } else if(e.type == IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR){
        trace("FILE DOES NOT EXIST");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility class I developed that handle a check weather a file exists or not.  Here's the code: 
https://github.com/eladelrom/eladlib/blob/master/EladLibFlex/src/com/elad/framework/utils/FileExistsUtil.as

And implementation looks like this:

```
var fileExists:FileExistsUtil = new FileExistsUtil();
fileExists.checkFile("file.jpg", 
function(eventType:String):void
{
 trace(eventType);
}, 
function(errorType:String, text:String):void
{
 trace(errorType+": "+text);
});
```

Comment: The link is fixed now to point to the project location on github